# MS Project 2013 resource graph

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

I am using the standard calendar.  Have a resource available 100% of the time.  When I add the first task, a 1 hr task, when I look at the resource graph it shows at 100%,  I have it set for an 8 hour day, so I would have thought that the graph would show around 12%.  Am I misunderstanding the resource graph or is this a configuration issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish - you have a task with a 1 day (8 hour duration).  During that 1 day, you'd like the resource to only work 1 hour?

First - show the Task Form in the lower pane (View Ribbon, Split View group, Details)

Create the task and set the duration to 1 day, and then make sure the task is Fixed Duration. Use the Task form to select Fixed Duration and click OK.

In the task form, select the resource and enter 1 hour of work.  Click OK to make the assignment.  The Assignment unit will show 100% - but if you show the Resource Usage view Or Task Usage View and add the Peak field - you'll see the peak is 13%.

The Resource Graph will also show 13%.

Comment: I have an 8 hour day, but 1 task is 1 hour long.  I thought the resource graph showed the allocation of work with respect to the work day.  (a 1 hour task in an 8 hour day)

Comment: No.  The resource graph show the allocation of the resource based upon task assignment - not based upon a day.  If the task is 1 hour duration with 1 hour of work - the assignment is 100% for that one hour.   You can certainly change the scale of the Resource Graph to show hours.  May I also suggest that planning down to the level of an hour long task may be too detailed?  My concern is that you will spend all of your time managing a Project file - and not the project.  You can change the default graph from Peak to % Work Allocated if that helps.

Comment: This is very helpful.  I was trying to use this graph to look at my resources and see who has bandwidth on the project and who does not.  I am not really planning down to the hour, that is just what I was playing with as an example.  Thanks so much for the info...

Comment: You're welcome.  You might also find the Resource Usage view with Remaining Availability added to the timescaled (right hand side) portion is helpful.  You can easily collapse to just show resource names and view availability for multiple resources with one look.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the feedback.